# MySQL Workbench -- First Connection "Internal Error"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to SQL and MySQL Workbench. Upon creating my first connection, I tested it and it passed, but when I hit 'OK", I got this error. Anyone know what it means? Thanks:

"Internal Error

Exception caught while processing action from home screen: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.autoDetectLocalInstance"

Comment: I assume you are on Windows. Did you install a MySQL server? You need one if you want to test local connections. But it is not necessary to have a local server to work with MySQL Workbench. Hence it should not throw an error (if you like, file a bug report for that at http://bugs.mysql.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try to start MySql Workbench with admin privileges.

For Xubuntu working:

**sudo mysql-workbench**